# Accessing a custom view from the xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, custom-view

In an Android application, I have created a custom view extending the `View` class. I want to declare an object of my class in the xml layout file but, even after many tries, the application unexpectedly stops when the `setContentView` call is executed (that's what the popup windows which appears says).
In my view class, which is declared in my `MainActivity` file as public, I have two constructors : one with only the `Context` as parameter and one with a `Context` and an `AttributeSet` parameters. And I have overridden the `onDraw` function.
This class is in my source package, named `org.me.myapp`.
In the layout file, I declare the object I want to insert like this :

```
    <org.me.myApp.MainActivity.myView"
    android:id="@+id/View"
    android:layout_below="@id/toto"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Yar said, you should extend View or ViewGroup to create custom layout element, and use that class name in your layout xml. Not member variable what it looks you're trying to do. After inflating your layout you can access your custom view with;

```
org.me.myapp.MyView myView = (org.me.myapp.MyView) findViewById(R.id.MYVIEWID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare your custom layout as a separate class, for example: **org.me.myapp.MyView**   and relate to it in your xml file like this:

```
<org.me.myapp.MyView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: So how about accepting it? ;) You can mark the answer as the right answer regardless of how many experience points you have.